# What's the best way to set a path to an audio file to an id dynamically?

Tags: android

What's the best way to set a path to an audio file to an id dynamically? And to have the app remember the newly set path for the future? (I guess we can't reset the xml files dynamically?)

Comment: Elaborate more for your question.

Comment: If you mean an R.raw.etc, you can't do this at all.  Learn about other options: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: I have an audio file to be played upon clicking a clickable view, but I want to give the user the option to select a different audio file for that clickable view.  And I want the app to remember the new setting.

Comment: BTW, why does the audio file I want to play be in the Resources folder?  Why can't it be in some arbitrary directory under root?  I should be able to access it via getExternalStorageDirectory() and then play it via MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

player.setDataSource(“/mnt/sdcard/media/audiofile.mp3”);